# How to insert different text with different format on each page in Libre Office Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, writer

How can I add a different text to each header and footer of each page in LibreOffice Writer? If I edit the header of a page, the text automatically changes on the others. I want them to behave independently.

EDIT: What I would like to achieve is this: let's say I have 7 pages, the first one doesn't have neither a header or a footer, it's just a simple page with an image. 
The second page should have an "INDEX" header and a footer at the bottom of the page with the page number "2" on the right. The third page should have another header, or better a header with a different text, different text-size and with italic style, and the footer should have the page number "3", and so on.

If I click Insert->Fields->Number of pages I get the total of the pages of my document and this is not what I am looking for. But also clicking on Insert->Fields->Number of page doesn't help cause if I have e.g. the "INDEX" page and I click on Insert->Fields->Number of page, I get the number "3" instead of the number "2". Also I have noticed that my footer style is different on some pages, how can I make it the same for every page?

Comment: Thank you for your response! This really comforts me. So you let's say that I still need to put the page number in the footer at the bottom on the right on every page. How can I do that? Using Insert->Fields->Number of pages didn't work for me neither Insert->Fields->Number of page. Sorry for my ignorance in LibreOffice but I really would like to figure out this basic things.
And about the different Headers, if there's a way to simply write a different text on each page header, please, could you explain me how to do that? Thank you for your attention!

Comment: I edited the question, please take a look :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For different page numbering, you will have to use [**`page styles`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Using_page_styles).  If your document contains a front page, one or more index pages, and the main content pages, you could create three different page styles (frontmatter, index, maincontent). **To change from one page style to the next one, you need to set manual page breaks, telling LibreOffice which page style to use after the page break:** Menu `Insert` -> `Manual Break`:

[image]

Using the "`Style`" ComboBox, you can select the page style to use for the pages **following** the break.

For each page style, you can set different headers / footers, e.g. to hide page numbering on the front page. Also, you can [**`set the page numbering to start with 1 instead of the "physical" page number`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Page_numbering#Example:_Restart_page_numbering:_a_preface) (for example, if the front page doesn't count as page 1, you could set the following page style to start with 1 instead 2).

**The most important point is diving the document in logical units using page styles**. After this is done, you can set different paragraph styles for each page element (header, footer), allowing to set a different text size only for the header of the "index" part of your document.

Comment: Thank you for your response, how can I add different styles to each page for a page? I just try to use Styles and formatting and I have create two styles 'Main-Page' and 'Index-Page', and I have set the first page to use the 'Main-Page' style. Then the secondo page which should have the 'Index-Page' style but when I try to set it the 'Index-Page' style is set to the first page (it replaces its 'Main-Page' style) intead of set it to the second page which is what I need. Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: I made it, Alleluja I made it, thanks man, I found out that if you select the next-style of a page you can select a custom one, is it the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Using the "Next Style" option works **only if you want to change the page style together with the next page break** - in other words, LO Writer **keeps the current style only for the current page**. If you want to apply the current style for the next three or four pages, you shouldn't use "Next Style"; instead, insert a manual break after the third / fourth page, together with a style change.